# jquery: how to remove the handler setup by .click()?

Tags: jquery

I found sometimes I hook up 2 functions to the buttun, using .click(function(){}), is it possible for me to remove the prior attached function before I hook up new one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not using an anonymous delegate like that. You can .unbind a named function though.

**UPDATE**

Actually you can call .unbind() with no arguments to remove all handlers or .unbind('click') to remove all handlers for a particular event.

Comment: +1 for actually showing how to use it to remove click handler.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has [unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways:

```
function foo(){
  //do stuff
}
function bar(){
  //do more
}
jQ.click(foo).click(bar);
jQ.unbind(foo);
```

or

```
jQ.bind('click.foo', function(){
  //do stuff
});
jQ.click(function(){
  //do more
});
jQ.unbind('.foo');
```